# set env before bash initialization

Tags: bash, environment-variables, terminal-emulator

I am creating new tab to run my command, and kill it when not needed.

- $ roxterm --tab -e top
- $ pkill -f top

(gnome-terminal is preferred, but doesn't support new tab to execute given command; splitting open & run fails to pkill).

My command requires a setup.sh script setting environment variables to be called prior to execution. However,

- $ roxterm --tab -e "source setup.sh; mycommand"

fails, with the error line 1: source not found, as the bash environment is not yet initialized in the just being created roxterm env. How to circumvent.

One option i can think of is to create below script, myscript.sh

- source setup.sh
- mycommand

but i'd like to avoid creating scripts for each of my commands, and be able to kill it with pkill -f mycommand

Comment: Have you tried explicitely calling `bash` ? Something like `roxterm --tab -e "bash -c 'source setup.sh; mycommand' "`

Comment: What happens if you use `. setup.sh` instead of `source setup.sh`?

Comment: @Aserre, this basically runs bash and something inside it. It does run, but pkill -e mycommand doesn't close the terminal.